# A question proving a variant of the handshake theorem

Tags: summation, induction

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and assume $n≥1$. Suppose you are at a party with $n$ people (including yourself). At the end of the party, define a person’s parity as *odd* if they have shaken hands with an odd number of people, and *even*, if they have shaken hands with an even number of people. Prove that the number of people of odd parity must be even.

I'm thinking that this question will involve proving the summation of something using induction. However, i'm not sure what I actually need to prove.

Comment: This is equivalent to the handshake theorem. You can do it by induction on the number of times hands are shaken.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a graph, this means there are an even number of vertices of odd degree. Let's suppose otherwise, that there are an odd number of vertices of odd degree. Then

$$ \sum_{v \ : \ \deg v \equiv 1 \pmod{2}} \deg v \equiv 1 \pmod{2} $$

and notice that the parity doesn't change when the vertices of even degree are added. But the Handshake Lemma states that the sum of all degrees is even, contradiction. Hence there must be an even number of odd-degree vertices.

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to phrase this as a proof by contradiction. What you show is that the parity of the sum of the degrees is the parity of the number of vertices of odd degree, then the handshake theorem says that this is even.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$ be the number of handshakes done by the first person and define $x_i$ in a similar manner. Now consider the sum of all $x_1$. At the beginning it's even and note that each handshake adds 2 to the sum, as exactly two of the numbers increase by 1. So going like this, handshake by handshake we get that at the end the sum of handshakes is even. Now how many summands can be odd in an even sum?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the number of people with odd parity, $b$ be the number people with even parity and $e$ be the number of pairs (pairs of two people that shakes hand). Now, suppose for a contradiction that $a$ is an odd number. Then number of all hand shakes is odd because it is $$a \cdot (odd \ number)+b \cdot(even \ number)$$ But this is impossible because when $2$ people shake hands, total number of hand shakes increase by $2$, which is even. So $a$ cannot be odd. So $a$ is even.

We could also finish the proof by saying $2e = a \cdot (odd \ number)+b \cdot(even \ number)$ because if there are $e$ many pairs, number of all hand shakes is $2e$.